# Codeigniter simple SQL query

Tags: sql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

My query work fine on Phpmyadmin but i try to convert this one to codeigniter query type and i dont know how with nested query. So, i want to inject this query with normal SQL format:

```
select * from conversations c join messages m on m.mconv_num = c.cnum where c.cuser2 = 2 and not exists (select * from messages m2 where m2.mconv_num = m.mconv_num and m2.mtime > m.mtime);
```

I try with this query:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM conversations c JOIN messages m ON m.mconv_num = c.cnum WHERE c.cuser2 = 2 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM messages m2 WHERE m2.mconv_num = m.mconv_num AND m2.mtime > m.mtime)';
$this->db->query($query);
```

But i have this error:

> A Database Error Occurred

```
No tables used 
SELECT *
```

Screenshot of the error: https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/03/5/1516363991-sans-titre.png

So, if someone can help me to execut my query or convert this one to codeigniter format. Thanks you !

**MODEL:**

```
  public function get_conversations_last_message_by_id($userLoginID)
    {
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM conversations c JOIN messages m ON m.mconv_num = c.cnum WHERE c.cuser2 = $userLoginID AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM messages m2 WHERE m2.mconv_num = m.mconv_num AND m2.mtime > m.mtime)';
        $this->db->query($query);

        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post your connectionstring

Comment: The database is autoload (this is the good answer ?)

Comment: Are you familiar with the Query Builder? That's the usual way to build queries in CodeIgniter? Is there a reason you're using direct SQL?

Comment: Also, a database error occurred, do you know how to get that error message? Have you turned PHP error reporting on full?

Comment: Yes i use Codeigniter for a lot of personnal project but never with nested query.. I want to make manually because I dont know how to make this query on codeigniter :/

Comment: which version of CI you are using?

Comment: did you check if a simple query returns results? like `SELECT * FROM conversations` ?

Comment: @VK321 I use V3.1.6

Comment: @VK321 Thanks you, i wait

Comment: i doubt that this has anything to do with CI - try vickels answer first...

Comment: @VK321 No, i try only "SELECT * FROM conversations" and i have the same error, I have the impression he stop after the '*'

Comment: Nope, the problem is not in the query. Problem is in db connection. recheck all connection.

Comment: So, i check all. When i make a query with codeigniter format (this->db->where...) its work but not with my other query.. its on the same file

Comment: possible to share your full code?

Comment: I update my post with my controller. The database is on autoload and its work fine on my other function.

Comment: So.. i solve my problem, i forget to remove the this db get at the end of the query... sorry to wasting your time... thanks man!